# What extensions assigned to notepad.exe by default?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, file-association, notepad

What file extensions are assigned to **NOTEPAD.EXE** *by default* in Windows (XP/7) ?

I havent access to Windows now, and my googling  for *list of default file associations windows* gives zilion links how to restore the defaults - but not the list itself ;(.

Can anyone helps?

Comment: why do you want to know this ? in case you want a more powerful alternative, try notepad++.

Comment: @blasto Simply need to know what extensions are ALREADY defaultly associated in windows to notepad.exe, because notepad exe is installed in windows. Have you windows in hands? Can you please check and answer what extensions are associated with notepad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.txt and .csv files are opened by default in Notepad. Remember though, as other programs get installed, associations may change.

Also, it is the default when editing .cmd, .bat, .vbs, .htm, .html, .css files by right-clicking and choosing Edit

Comment: On systems that have Excel installed, `.csv` is commonly mapped to Excel. On systems that have Microsoft Word, the **Edit** option for `.htm` (and related) files is often mapped to Word, and is sometimes not present at all.

Comment: True, but the OP asked about the *defaults*. Not all systems have MS Office installed, and it certainly isn't installed when you install Windows from scratch

Answer (score 1):

I’ve found that `.log` is typically mapped to Notepad.

Also, many file types have Notepad on their "Open with" submenu.

Comment: great - thanx too ;)